# Can't login to some sites after changing password

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

My password was remembered by a browser and I forgot to save it somewhere else too.

After accidentally erasing all saved logins, I now had to recreate mine. I did it successfully, and can access some of the SE sites (MathOverflow, Mathematics, Mathematica, TeX, ...) but not some others (e.g. Ask Ubuntu, Super User). What does this depend on? What can I do to recover these too?